# Decucibility of FOL well formed formulas

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru2hH.jpg)

[image]

The problem is in the attached image. I know how to evaluate the truth table for (Exy $\Rightarrow$ Txy), Exy, Txy. I'm confused by the description of the problem as if p, q, are the same in both well formed formulas then the truth value for (Exy $\Rightarrow$ Txy) will be the same. I am also a bit confused by being asked to find particular values for x and y because it seems to me that the truth value of the WFFs are dependent upon **all** values for x and y.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

The key point is that variable $y$ in $Txy$ is *free* in the premise while it is *bound* in the conclusion.